# How to fix CachingSection Duplicate Section on IIS

Tags: html, .net, iis-7.5

In IIS 7.5 when i select a page writed in html (not created in .Net), I have an error 500. When I go to this *.html page, but in the rest of this web app works fine.

Investigating a little more, I get the following error: "**There is a duplicate 'cachingSection' section defined**"

I tried to do the following:

*Compare web.config root file and machine.config for duplicated 'cachingSection' sections. And both files are ok.

*Compare web.config root file with web.config located on Views folder. And both files not have 'duplicated sections'.
*In my PC, i ran this web app and works fine.

This .Net app in my pc works with .Net 4

¿Any idea how to solve this error?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Are the application pools on both computers running the same .NET version? I assume you copied over the web.config file when you copied the other web pages?

Comment: Thanks haxtbh, but in both pc's (One is my pc and the other is a server) using .Net 4.0 version for this app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you don't have any additional web.config files "lurking" in the folders.  I have done this when I tried to refer to class projects inside a web project.

Comment: Anthony Horne: I'll try your advise and i'll tell you

Comment: Thank's for your answer!